# Java - Open a PDF file from within the JAR in a Java window (JPanel, JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jar

I have a Java desktop application (a jar that will be used in a Mac OS .app and a Windows .exe). This Jar will contain a PDF file and I need to show this file in a Java Swing window. 
How is this possible? Can be done without any additional library, like ICEPdf?

Comment: Java has no built-in support for PDFs.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Read the manual for the lib you'll use. Each lib has its own API.

Comment: I meant not with ICEPdf, but if you have any other suggestion on how to do this the easyest way?

Comment: PDF rendering is a very hard job. To avoid it, you can convert your PDF to a bundle of "png" images. This format has the built-in support in Java. The only one you need is to provide an Icon, which displays more than one image.

Comment: The problem is, that I will need to use a multi page PDF file, which will contain formated text and images. So, the transformation to a PNG might not be the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried it? For your case it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

With this function, you will use the default PDF viewer that your OS have installed

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(*path to PDF*));
```

Comment: The PDF file is inside the JAR file. This code will not open a file from within the JAR.

Comment: If your PDF is inside the jar that includes your application (like you said in your answer) this will work... You just need to put the correct path to the PDF file